# How do I read a specific column of characters from a dataset

Tags: c++, dataset, char

I'm working with a dataset of attributes in a text file which looked something like this:

```
e,x,y,w,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g
e,f,y,y,t,l,f,c,b,w,e,r,s,y,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,y,p
e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,w,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g
e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,w,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,m
e,x,y,n,t,l,f,c,b,w,e,r,s,y,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,y,g
e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,g
e,x,f,g,f,n,f,c,n,g,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,y,u
e,b,s,y,t,l,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how I can easily read characters from a given column. For example, if I wanted to read from the 3rd column, the output would be "yyssysfs". I can't figure out how to do it though. Does anyone know what I might be able to do?

Comment: Is this homework? Hint: use a 2d char array to store the text and try looping c[x][3] where x is the loop variable.

Answer (score 1):

Read each line, one at a time, maybe removing the commas, and put in a `std::vector`. To get the third column, just loop over all strings in the vector, getting the third (if commas are removed) character from the string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution using the dark internals of the iostreams:

```
struct dataset_ctype : std::ctype<char>
{
  mask table[table_size];
public:
  dataset_ctype(size_t refs = 0) : std::ctype<char>(table, false, refs) {
    std::fill(table, table+table_size, (mask)alpha);
    table[','] = (mask)space;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::string inp = 
    "e,x,y,w,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g\n"
    "e,f,y,y,t,l,f,c,b,w,e,r,s,y,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,y,p\n"
    "e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,w,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g\n"
    "e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,w,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,m\n"
    "e,x,y,n,t,l,f,c,b,w,e,r,s,y,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,y,g\n"
    "e,b,s,w,t,a,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,k,s,g\n"
    "e,x,f,g,f,n,f,c,n,g,e,e,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,y,u\n"
    "e,b,s,y,t,l,f,c,b,k,e,c,s,s,w,w,p,w,o,p,n,s,g\n";

  std::istringstream is(inp);
  is.imbue(std::locale(is.getloc(), new dataset_ctype));

  const int column = 2;
  while (is) {
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> ii(is);
    std::advance(ii, column);
    std::cout << *ii << '\n';
    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
}
```

Comment: oh dear I wasn't aware you could do it like this. But isn't there a nicer API for this, like setting a delimiter, or just using a `split(line, ',')`?

Comment: The easiest way would be using `getline(s, ',')`, but this is the only way I'm aware of that has no inner loop ;)

Comment: You could also use a filtering streambuf, which converted all `','` to `' '`.  If it is the field which is needed, however, you'll need nested loops somewhere, regardless of the solution.  If it is simply a column, however, just indexing into the string with the line is sufficient.  (The use of `std::advance` and `std::istream_iterator` is rather clever, however.  It would be even cleverer if it would do something intelligent if the input wasn't correctly formatted; if, for example, one line only had two fields.)

Answer (score 1):

What, exactly, is your definition of column.  By the usual
definition, the list of characters in the third column would be
`"xfbbxbxb"` (and the list of characters in the second column
would be `",,,,,,,,"`).  What you seem to want is the list of
characters in the third *field*.

For the list of characters in a column, the solution is trivial.
Just read line by line (`std::getline`), and index into the line
with the column number (after verifying that the line really is
long enough, of course).

For the list of characters in a field, you'll have to break each
line down into fields, probably putting the results into an
`std::vector<std::string>`, and then index into this vector.

If this is a poorly worded homework problem, and you are
guaranteed that 1) each field has exactly one character, and 2)
fields are separated by a single comma, with no additional white
space, then you can map fields to columns (`2 * fieldId - 1`
gives the column).  Having done this, you can use the solution
for characters in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::ifstream` to open the file, and then have a `while` loop whose condition is `std::getline(file,line)`, where `line` is an `std::string`. You can work out which position the character is in the line from the column number, `i`, as just being `2 * i` (if the first column is `i == 0`). To get that character from the line, just use `std::string::operator[]`.  No need to parse the line at all. Then push the character you get from each line into a `std::vector<char>`.